# Как скрыть строки с текстом в исполняемых файлах PE (.exe)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, exe

При создании .ехе файла туда помещаются все строковые литералы, используемые в программе. Эти данные лежат в открытом виде и получить их даже штатными средствами довольно легко:

[image: картинка1]

Какие существуют способы защиты .ехе от подобного? (возможны проприетарные решения и собственные)

Comment: Компрессия/шифрование исполняемого файла... например.

Comment: Можно 1)шифровать строки в исходнике  2)можно делать строки не в строковом виде (например звеньями, или деревьями - дерево позволяет "сжать" немного) а за тем собирать функций в строку, когда нужно. 3)Можно сделать словарь - и делать список слов. Словарь в будущем можно сжать.

Comment: @Akina нашел mpress, но он выглядит старым, может подскажете современные аналоги

Comment: Вот даже на википедии по словам "Упаковка исполняемых файлов" отыскивается статья со вполне себе актуальными фамилиями пакеров...

Comment: @Akina а если упаковка не нужна? Особенно с учетом того, что на нее нередко аггрятся антивирусы, а нужно только строки скрыть? )

Comment: *нужно только строки скрыть?* Скрываем кодом, собирающим нужные строки из фрагментов и/или с обработкой. `MessageNNN = Concat(partNNN_1, partNNN_2,...).ByteXOR(mask_NNN)`

Comment: Дубликат, по-моему, не соответствует вопросу - тут хотят скрывать только "человеческие" строки, а там - сам код...

Comment: @Mikhailo на самом деле соответствует) я очень обще сформулировал вопрос, так как не разбираюсь в теме. Основной целью является скрытие "человеческих" данных в .ехе, упаковка не нужна. вопрос-дубликат хотя бы помог мне найти нужный вектор движения, дальше - дело техники)